# What email service should I use for my React+Node based Ecommerce Website?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, e-commerce

I'm working on an E-Commerce project for a while now and want to set up email functionality for the customers. I want to send them emails regarding new releases and other company related stuff (newsletters,etc.).

I've used mailgun in my previous personal projects. What would you recommend I should be using here because this is a big project and I want a good performance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install Node mailer package with npm:

```
npm install nodemailer
```

Then include it in a relevant email message script:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

For more info, you can consult this easy to understand guide: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp

Comment: Will nodemailer be good enough for an E-Commerce? Sending emails regularly with custom template. Will nodemailer be able to do the job?

Comment: Are you concerned that your security might be compromised if you use it?

Comment: Security is definitely a concern here, but I also would like it to be smooth in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use SES (Simple Email Service) on AWS. It's not expensive at all (0.10$) 1000 emails.
You just have to connect your NodeJS API to the SES service when setup (many tutorials exists).
It's cheap, secure, and if you have a big quantity of users on your website, SES will surely not crash.

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll definitely check out this one.